# Using Custom IHttpModule to save information on changing pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a site where users can use a particular page to enter in lots of information.  If the user navigates away from that page, I'd like to store a Session variable so that the user may return to that page and retain all the information added previously.

I've created a custom IHttpModule.  My intent was to utilize that to take notice when users click away from the page.  Then access the page, grab the variables from it, and store them for re-population later.

Here's what I've got:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication application)
{
    application.BeginRequest += (new EventHandler(this.Application_MovePages));
}

private void Application_MovePages(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;
    HttpContext context = application.Context;
    System.Web.Ui page;

    if (HttpContext.Current.Handler != null)
    {
        page = (System.Web.Ui.Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    }
}
```

The problem is HttpContext.Current.Handler is always null.  I'm missing something here.

Comment: How would you get the information in the page if it's not submited to the server?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to ensure that the user's information is constantly saved (as in google docs does with your drafts/documents for example).
To do this you constantly need to serialize the form and send it off via an ajax request to save it. When the user navigates away, you should prompt them if the doc isn't saved. If they choose to save it, then serialize the form with jQuery and send it off to a page for saving. The response from that page would contain a cookie session value (guid) that you would use to look up this information later. I would do this over SSL as this token could be sniffed on the wire.

You don't need an http module for this, you can simply have whatever your page is that would save this UNLESS you want something that sits on top of your application that can do this for any page. You still then have a problem in that this is very page specific. You need to develop the 'save' routine to work via ajax, serialize the form information, save it, and have a load mechanism.

Again.. keep in mind 'how' you are saving this info when a user decides to leave the page. That's something you need to determine how you want handled.